# Display user info got it from Service with blocks in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, block, afnetworking, objective-c-blocks

I want to display user info. I am trying to do it with AFNetworking AFHttpClient and blocks. This is my code. Do you know what could I do? I do this to fulfil a tableView in other View and it works. But here I cant display a simple UILabel with an user name

```
#import "YPProfileViewController.h"
#import "YPNetworkManager.h"
#import "Developer+Helper.h"

@interface YPProfileViewController (){
    SelectionSuccessBlock2 successBlock;

}

@end

@implementation YPProfileViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UILabel *userNameLbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 40, 100, 20)];
    NSString *userNameStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name "];
    [userNameLbl setText:userNameStr];
    [self.view addSubview:userNameLbl];
    [self loadUserInfoFromService];
}
```

Here I use a block

```
-(void)loadUserInfoFromService{

    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    successBlock = ^(NSDictionary *newDev) {
     NSLog(@"data ");
        if (newDev){
            [weakSelf showData:newDev];
        }

    };

    [ypNetManager getUserInformation:successBlock error:NULL];

}
```

I display the label here:

```
-(void)showData:(NSDictionary *) devInfo{
    Developer *dev = [Developer createDevelopertWithDictionary:devInfo];
    UILabel *userNameLbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 40, 100, 20)];
    NSString *userNameStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name : %@", dev.user_name];
    [userNameLbl setText:userNameStr];
    [self.view addSubview:userNameLbl];

}


@end
```

And this is the method that I use in my AFNetworking AFHttpClient CLient:

```
-(void)getUserInformation:(SelectionSuccessBlock2)success error:(SelectionErrorBlock)error {
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:kAPIProjectList parameters:nil];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:kTimeOutRequest];


    AFJSONRequestOperation *requestOperation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
        NSLog(@"data");

        NSLog(@"%@ Susscess JSNON Response: %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd),JSON);
        NSDictionary *devInfo = [[NSDictionary alloc] init ];
        devInfo = [JSON valueForKey:kTagUser];
         NSLog(@"data %@", devInfo);

        if (success) {
            success(devInfo);
        }

    }
    failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *aError, id JSON) {
        NSLog(@"%@ Failure JSNON Error%@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), aError);
        if (error) {
            error(aError);
        }
    }];


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I found it. It was just that I forget the last sentence.

`[requestOperation start];`

```
-(void)getUserInformation:(SelectionSuccessBlock2)success error:(SelectionErrorBlock)error {
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:kAPIProjectList parameters:nil];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:kTimeOutRequest];


        AFJSONRequestOperation *requestOperation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
            NSLog(@"data");

            NSLog(@"%@ Susscess JSNON Response: %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd),JSON);
            NSDictionary *devInfo = [[NSDictionary alloc] init ];
            devInfo = [JSON valueForKey:kTagUser];
             NSLog(@"data %@", devInfo);

            if (success) {
                success(devInfo);
            }

        }
        failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *aError, id JSON) {
            NSLog(@"%@ Failure JSNON Error%@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), aError);
            if (error) {
                error(aError);
            }
        }];
     [requestOperation start];

    }
```